# C++. Assignment operator of a pointer array in class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, stack

My task is to create the class `stack` using a pointer array. However, when I assign a variable of type `stack` to itself, the elements of the stack (or array) become garbage. So here's the code (fields are `array`, `stack_size` and `stack_capacity`):

```
stack& operator= (const stack& old)
{
    if (stack_size != old.stack_size) {//array and old.array could be the same
        delete[] array;
    }
    stack_size = old.stack_size;
    stack_capacity = old.stack_capacity;
    array = new int[stack_capacity];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < stack_size; ++i) {
        array[i] = old.array[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

However, when I run

```
std::cout << "Peek: " << c.peek() << "  Size: " << c.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << c << "\n\n";
```

the output (before assigning) is:

```
Peek: 300  Size: 6
{ -88, 99, -100, 0, 200, 300 }
```

and after assigning (stk = stk) is:

```
Peek: -842150451  Size: 6
{ -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451 }
```

What could be the problem? Is there anything I am missing? Thank you

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Please post your test code as you might be doing initialisation instead of assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `*this` and `old` are the same object, `this->array` is the same as `old.array`.
This means that you're copying the uninitialized data in

```
array = new int[stack_capacity];
```

into itself.

The traditional and quick fix is to check for self-assignment first,

```
if (this == &old)
    return *this;
```

A more modern solution is the "copy-and-swap" idiom, which you can read about online.